# In the 2nd temple period were either the tabernacle or the temple ever referred to as "heaven and earth"?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

I have read that in the 2nd temple period the tabernacle and/or the temple were referred to as "heaven and earth". And that the holy place was heaven and the outer court was earth? Is that so?

Comment: Where did you read it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional understanding is that the Temple is the place where heaven and earth meet, indeed this is what Jacob sensed when he woke up from his dream and saw angels going up and down a ladder, between heaven and earth ([Bereishit 28:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> וַיִּירָא֙ וַיֹּאמַ֔ר מַה־נּוֹרָ֖א הַמָּק֣וֹם הַזֶּ֑ה אֵ֣ין זֶ֗ה כִּ֚י
>   אִם־בֵּ֣ית אֱלֹהִ֔ים וְזֶ֖ה שַׁ֥עַר הַשָּׁמָֽיִם׃
>
> Shaken, he said, “How awesome is this place! This is none other than
>   the abode of God, and that is **the gateway to heaven**.”

The [Malbim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim) on this verse writes

> Jacob understood that this place was the site of the future Temple...
>   for **the Temple is the ladder, whereby heaven and earth kiss each
>   other**. Man's worship ascends upward, and the Divine providence
>   descends thereby.

(taken from [this aish article](https://www.aish.com/h/9av/ht/48958971.html) by R Ahron Lopiansky)